# Hidden and visible classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to figure out how Bootstrap responsive features are working. I have one div and I want it to be hidden on mobile devices:

```
<div class="text-center hidden-xs">
     Content
</div>
```

I checked this page on the phone and div is still visible. But if I do the following thing:

```
<div class="text-center visible-md visible-lg">
     Content
</div>
```

then my div is hidden on mobile devices and visible on desktops.

I thought that "`hidden-xs`" is equivalent to "`visible-md visible-lg`". Can you explain what the difference?

Comment: Your first snippet of code does hide the DIV.  Maybe you have something else on your page that is making it visible?

Comment: probably that your `.text-center` has some `display: ` on it that comes after the bootstrap css?

Comment: @LloydBanks I checked css style of this div and I didn't set display property anywhere

Comment: @Dejan.S I removed .text-center class, but still have the same problem, so I think it's about bootstrap css and device width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible you tested it from a viewport with a width at/over 768px? Because `hidden-xs` is equivalent to `visible-sm visible-md visible-lg`, not just `visible-md visible-lg` as you had posted. If you had been viewing on a small viewport, it would have been visible for the first example and hidden for the second.

You can also test this by simply resizing your browser window, if you're not doing any media-queries or other things that would be specific to your phone, just as a sanity-check.

There's a useful table for visible vs. hidden in the docs at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes, so check that out if you're confused.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I use hidden-xs instead of hidden-sm.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the div with the following Javascript/JQuery script. This does not need bootstrap classes. (which I am also not familiar).
The following  script targets mobile android and iphone, you can target also other devices.

```
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1)  {
           $('.text-center hidden-xs').css('visibility','hidden'); 
     }

  if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('iphone') > -1)  {
           $('.text-center hidden-xs').css('visibility','hidden'); 
     }
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use a jquery script targeting (a potentially large/changing number of) specific devices to solve this, since (s)he is concerned with responsive design based off viewport width. If you absolutely should need to override something at a high level that isn't wrapped in a column, etc., it'd still be best to use CSS Media Queries for the viewport size since that's consistent with the rest of bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I would like to solve this problem with bootstrap css classes or at least with my custom css.